# CREATE TABLE AS SELECT with GTID

Tags: mysql, replication, gtid

I am trying to migrate to MySQL/Percona server 8.0 and GTID based replication and have stumbled upon the issue where `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` is not allowed using GTID.

The tables that are created are for materializing complex selects which span several tables and can not be replaced by a simple `CREATE TABLE LIKE`.

Since these are slow and complex selects they already use the `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT LIMIT 0` + `INSERT INTO SELECT` pattern to get around the metadata lock issues. This in my mind should mean that the code I am using already is replication safe with GTIDs, but all `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` are blocked when using `enforce-gtid-consistency` (even though https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/01/10/why-avoid-create-table-as-select-statement/ suggests otherwise), so I need a workaround.

I have already found that replacing the `CREATE TABLE AS` with a `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AS` together with a `CREATE TABLE LIKE` may get around the problem, but it seems like a ugly hack to me so I wonder if there is any better way of getting around the issue?

Comment: does this complexity go away with `binlog_format=ROW`?

Comment: @danblack nope, I get `Statement violates GTID consistency: CREATE TABLE ... SELECT` regardless